# Элементы не растягиваются на весь контейнер при justify-content: space-between

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, flexbox

Имеется следующий код:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Bebas Neue, sans-serif;
  font-stretch: condensed;
  color: white;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 1920px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 66%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black
}

header {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 0.95em;
}

.logo {
  width: 110px;
  background: red
}

.search_bar {
  width: 23.9em;
  height: 1.67em
}

.search_bar input {
  font-size: 1.13em;
  font-stretch: condensed;
  padding-left: 6px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.search_bar img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
}

.search_bar input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #9e9e9e;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #9e9e9e;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #9e9e9e;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #9e9e9e;
}

.banner_right {
  width: 20em;
  background: green
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en-US">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Aditii - Main Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="search_bar">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <div class="banner_right">
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

В указанном случае, *header* имеет свойство `justify-content: space-between`. Несмотря на это, элементы не растягиваются на всю ширину контейнера: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXvaGB
Как это исправить?

Comment: Попробуй задать в % ширину для `.search_bar, .logo, .banner_right`

Comment: Попробовал. Увы, не помогло - справа все еще остается пространство

Comment: @AlexandrJärvi определитесь, для начала, с помощью чего Вы будете верстать - `float` или `flex`, и тогда ошибок будет меньше гораздо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалите вот это(кстати зачем оно вам?)

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Переделайте значение в проценты или wrapper-у какое то минимальное значение и все будет хорошо.
Еще можно задать input-у

```
    height: calc(100% - 4px);
```

чтобы оно было той же высоты что и элементы сбоку.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо за ответ

Comment: всегда пожалуйста